# Profile View Update

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to create a query which will update each person's profile views when a member accesses their profile. For some reason it does not update, I am sure it would have worked. Here is my lines:

```
<?php
$name = $_REQUEST['username'];
$profile = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='$name'");
$uprofile = mysql_fetch_assoc($profile);

$username = $uprofile['user_name'];
$profilev = $uprofile['profile_views'];

mysql_query("UPDATE users SET profile_views +1 WHERE user_name='$name'");

?>
```

So, On my profile, It displays their username successfully, and it displays the default value of the database for profile_views which ofcourse, is `0`. so it is reading correctly, I am just having issues updating the users profile_views.

Comment: `SET profile_views  = profile_views+1 WHERE` But you should better stop using deprecated `mysql*` functions

Comment: Thank you, but just because its depreated, why should i not use it? i don't really know anything about PDO

Comment: just read some there http://stackoverflow.com/a/12860046/4421474

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a mistake try

```
"UPDATE users 
 SET profile_views = profile_views  +1 
 WHERE user_name='$name'"
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way I could also limit it so to if the same user re-visits the other members page, it would not update again for like, 24 hours?

Comment: You should store a realtion between user and visitors with the dae of last visist the check fo this date before perform the increment of visit..

Comment: Why should the OP "try" this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.